# ID story about survivors of nova

Tags: story-identification, space, post-apocalyptic

Short story, sun has gone nova, a family is translated into waveforms traveling in space.  The youngest family member, a girl I believe, slowly realizes this, and her realization, followed by reassurance from other family members, ends the story.  Written in English, maybe from the 1980s.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you remember any more details about this story - e.g. when did you read it, how old was it, was it part of a collection or anthology, was it in English or translated, where was it set?

Comment: I think I read it in the 1980s.  It was short, so would be in a collection.  English.  --  Thanks for the tips about asking, says this newb.

Comment: Probably "Daisy, in the Sun" by Connie Willis.

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for editing! [You can also find more tips here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31394), and checklists which may help to jog your memory. (I was going to propose ["Thundering Worlds" by Edmond Hamilton](http://fantasticworlds-jordan179.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/thundering-worlds-1934-by-edmo.html), but now it's clear that you mean a human family and not a family of planets or planetary representatives.)

Comment: @DraganMilosevic Post that as an answer? :-) (There's a handy [Goodreads link](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/209704.Daisy_in_the_Sun) if you don't have the book to hand and need some supporting info/links.)

Comment: Honorable mention for the *Star Trek TNG* episode "[The Inner Light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Inner_Light_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))".